# Symfony PHP Missing Argument Error when using Join

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

Hi I am using a PHP Symfony project and am trying to use the generated model peer class to make a query.

The model has generated the method "doSelectJoinMeetingItems" which is supposed to join my Meeting Actions Table to my Meeting Items table (see a quote of the generated code below).

However, when using this method I get the following error: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for sfComponent::__construct(),` - see in full below.

Does anyone know why this is happening? All I am doing is using Symfonys own generated methods to try and get data through my ORM to me!

Thanks for your time,

**My code:**

Inside MeetingMeetingsPeer

```
return self::doSelectJoinMeetingItems(new Criteria());
```

The auto generated baseMeetingActionsPeer

```
public static function doSelectJoinMeetingItems(Criteria $criteria, $con = null, $join_behavior = Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
{
    $criteria = clone $criteria;

    // Set the correct dbName if it has not been overridden
    if ($criteria->getDbName() == Propel::getDefaultDB()) {
        $criteria->setDbName(self::DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    MeetingActionsPeer::addSelectColumns($criteria);
    $startcol = (MeetingActionsPeer::NUM_COLUMNS - MeetingActionsPeer::NUM_LAZY_LOAD_COLUMNS);
    MeetingItemsPeer::addSelectColumns($criteria);

    $criteria->addJoin(MeetingActionsPeer::ITEM_ID, MeetingItemsPeer::ID, $join_behavior);

    // symfony_behaviors behavior
    foreach (sfMixer::getCallables(self::getMixerPreSelectHook(__FUNCTION__)) as $sf_hook)
    {
      call_user_func($sf_hook, 'BaseMeetingActionsPeer', $criteria, $con);
    }

    $stmt = BasePeer::doSelect($criteria, $con);
    $results = array();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $key1 = MeetingActionsPeer::getPrimaryKeyHashFromRow($row, 0);
        if (null !== ($obj1 = MeetingActionsPeer::getInstanceFromPool($key1))) {
            // We no longer rehydrate the object, since this can cause data loss.
            // See http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/ticket/509
            // $obj1->hydrate($row, 0, true); // rehydrate
        } else {

            $cls = MeetingActionsPeer::getOMClass(false);

            $obj1 = new $cls();
            $obj1->hydrate($row);
            MeetingActionsPeer::addInstanceToPool($obj1, $key1);
        } // if $obj1 already loaded

        $key2 = MeetingItemsPeer::getPrimaryKeyHashFromRow($row, $startcol);
        if ($key2 !== null) {
            $obj2 = MeetingItemsPeer::getInstanceFromPool($key2);
            if (!$obj2) {

                $cls = MeetingItemsPeer::getOMClass(false);

                $obj2 = new $cls();
                $obj2->hydrate($row, $startcol);
                MeetingItemsPeer::addInstanceToPool($obj2, $key2);
            } // if obj2 already loaded

            // Add the $obj1 (MeetingActions) to $obj2 (MeetingItems)
            $obj2->addMeetingActions($obj1);

        } // if joined row was not null

        $results[] = $obj1;
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    return $results;
}
```

**The Error in Full**

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for sfComponent::__construct(), called in /var/www/html/dev/meeting/lib/model/om/BaseMeetingActionsPeer.php on line 584 and defined in /var/www/html/dev/meeting/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/action/sfComponent.class.php on line 36

Warning: Missing argument 2 for sfComponent::__construct(), called in /var/www/html/dev/meeting/lib/model/om/BaseMeetingActionsPeer.php on line 584 and defined in /var/www/html/dev/meeting/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/action/sfComponent.class.php on line 36

Warning: Missing argument 3 for sfComponent::__construct(), called in /var/www/html/dev/meeting/lib/model/om/BaseMeetingActionsPeer.php on line 584 and defined in /var/www/html/dev/meeting/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/action/sfComponent.class.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined variable: context in /var/www/html/dev/meeting/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/action/sfComponent.class.php on line 38

Fatal error: Call to a member function getEventDispatcher() on a non-object in /var/www/html/dev/meeting/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/action/sfComponent.class.php on line 55
```

The lines 582 to 586 are as follows:

```
582    $cls = MeetingActionsPeer::getOMClass(false);
583    
584    $obj1 = new $cls();
585    $obj1->hydrate($row);
586    MeetingActionsPeer::addInstanceToPool($obj1, $key1);
```

Line 36 from sfComponnent.class.php

```
36    public function __construct($context, $moduleName, $actionName)
37      {
38        $this->initialize($context, $moduleName, $actionName);
39      }
```

Comment: Not sure if you have sorted this but the error you are getting is nothing to do with the query. I suspect some where you have include_component and have not specified a name or something.

Comment: Added above, although it's part of Symfonys core code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have located the problem, in Symfony 1.4 you cannot have a class that ends in **actions** for example UserActions or GroupActions (wish this was properly documented somewhere).

I wish this was better documented and the error was more useful!

> a classname (in the schema.yml) which ends with '%Actions' for example
>   UserActions? (symfony 1.4.10). An error was thrown when i added an
>   extra field (with validation) in the form of the object related to
>   this '*Actions'.

```
wrapped: Warning: Missing argument 2 for sfComponent::__construct(), called in 
/Users/Shared/Library/symfony-1.4.10/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php 
on line 301 and defined in /Users/Shared/Library/symfony-1.4.10/lib/action/sfComponent.class.php on line 36 
Warning: Missing argument 3 for sfComponent::__construct(), called in 
/Users/Shared/Library/symfony-1.4.10/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php 
on line 301 and defined in /Users/Shared/Library/symfony-1.4.10/lib/action/sfComponent.class.php on line 36]
```

See post at http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/ReservedWords